# fullcalendar, How to get the time down the calender side

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to know how to get the time down the side of the calender in 30 minute periods in the week and day views.

I have the following code.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next, today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultView:'basicWeek',
            axisFormat:'h(:mm)tt',
            slotMinutes:'30',
            firstHour:'6',
            minTime:'6',
            maxTime:'22',
            theme: true,
            weekMode:'variable',
            editable: false,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            incrementDate: date,
            events: function(start, end, callback) {
                $.ajax({

                   Ajax stuff

                });
            }, //end event
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                click event stuff
            }//end eventClick
        });
```

But the time does not display down the side of the calender. What options am I missing or can this be done at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
defaultView:'basicWeek'
```

To

```
defaultView:'agendaWeek'
```

Probably want to change your buttons also. (Use agendaWeek and/or AgendaDay)

Answer (score 0):

change slotMinutes and firstHour to be number literals, not strings